# Correct usage of Async BeginRead() Method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networkstream

BeginRead part of the server is like this:

```
    private void listen()
    {
        allDone.Reset();
        networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(newDataRecievedCallback), null);
        allDone.WaitOne(10);
    }

    private void newDataRecievedCallback(IAsyncResult rst)
    {
        try
        {
            int incomeDataSize = networkStream.EndRead(rst);
            lastRecievedBuffer = convertToString(buffer, incomeDataSize).Trim();
            cleanBuffer();

            if (IsValidXml(lastRecievedBuffer)) 
                parseXML(lastRecievedBuffer);
            allDone.Set();

            //Here I call the listen() method again               
            listen();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogSystem.saveServerError(ex.StackTrace, ex.Source);
        }
    }
```

Usage of NetworkStream:

```
    private NetworkStream networkStream;
    private TcpClient tcpClient;

    //this part is in the constructor of the Server class
    tcpClient = new TcpClient(loginData.Host, loginData.Port);
    networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
```

Is this the correct usage of BeginRead() or am I calling the Async BeginRead() Method like Sync logic?

Is there better way to do it witout calling the listen() method again?
Thank you!

Comment: How do you create `networkStream`? And what do you mean that 2 data can come in at the same time? Do you mean from two different senders?

Comment: sorry, only 1 sender in this case.

Comment: And could you show us the code you use to create the `networkStream`?

Comment: just edited the question, so you can check for

Comment: Several red flags: hoping it will only take 10 milliseconds is wishful thinking.  As is hoping that you'll get the entire xml document on the EndRead call.  It isn't otherwise obvious how you handle multiple connections.  Calling listen() again is otherwise correct, gets you the rest of the xml.

Comment: I don't understand how could 2 data come in at the same time. You're not listening for incoming connections, you create one connection to some server.

Comment: @svick you right 1 connection only for this example. I ll edit the question.